Plausible explanation for an alien parasitoid what reproduces by passing DNA information through light-waves? (James Kakalio’s “Miracle Exception”)
Hello and thank you for reading this.

Explanation
I was watching “Zygote” (2017), a Sci-Fi Horror short film by Neill Blomkamp
The monster of the film, the Zygote, is a creature which "transmitted gigabytes of data" via light waves into peoples' eyes to program them to fuse with it.
The Xenomorph from Alien is also similar. The Facehugger form infects people with the black-goo to restructure the host's cells, and assemble a Chestburster out of the host´s own biological materials.
So, using Zygote and Alien creature’s concepts, I wanted to design an extraterrestrial endoparasitoid predator that reproduces by passing DNA information through light-waves into people’s eyes, and uses the host's cells to assemble an embryo. Essentially a parasitoid that uses light as a medium to parasite rather than deposit eggs on a host or infect them through fluids.
I wanted to give a semi-plausible explanation for such biology to be plausible, but I understand such a concept flies directly into the realm of fantasy.
So, to at least give my story semi realism, I would be using James Kakalio’s rule of Miracle Exception: Every story is allowed one miracle exception to the laws of physics for the story to be still considered ¨realistic¨.

Question
Supposing my story will apply the rule of Miracle Exception. What would be a plausible way to explain how a parasitoid extraterrestrial predator reproduces by passing DNA information through light-waves?

Creature concept

Form: Quadruped creature, “drake” like shape.
Size: 2 meters high, 4 meters long.
Semi-Aquatic.
Seven “eyes” on its head.
Able to emit a red flash thought its “eyes”.
Able to  send DNA information through the red light to the
host/victim through his/her visual system, and through it into the host’s nervous system.
Use host’s own cells to create heterogenous cells and form an “embryo” inside host/victim.
Causes rapid cell reproduction.
The “red flash” can cover an effective area of a high school sports hall.


Thank you for your time to. If you can, I would be grateful for any help you can provide.

Is it important for the red light itself to be what is responsible?  I could write a decent answer using terahertz (see 1, 2, 3), but your question says the information is "sent through the red light".  If the red light were a byproduct of a phased array terahertz emitter, that would be another story...

It is more thematic the red colour to be sincere. The creature itself is an inspiration from the red dragon of Revelations, the story uses references from it since I consider the Greek references to be overused in scifi at this point. But it could be an intense colourless light or anything to be honest


Look here, Professor! The thing is hijacking the DNA of the lab mouse with light! How is this possible? - Only one way, lad:  the Universe is not real, we are actually living in the fantasies of some sci-fi geek who availed himself of a One Miracle Exception.


“The universe only allows one miracle.” “Ok. My miracle is infinite miracles.”

Could the red flash be accompanied by flash in wider part of EM spectrum? Targeted sunburn causing skin cancer mutations might get something plausible.

PS: never post the one miracle! Save that for whatever Worldbuilding cannot answer! :-)

RiboNucleic Acid (RNA)
Light going into the eye doesn't seem to do anything that can have far ranging consequences at first. Light reaches the eyes, which is translated to stimulated nerves, which sets off an electrical/chemical chain reaction in the brain that process the images. Based on the images there can be further more significant reactions. Think fear, happiness or a teenager seeing sexual stimuli. It is far fetched however. The light hitting the eyes does have one more function. It is producing RNA, a derivative of DNA.
To quote a random site I found made an excellent summary for my case:
"RNA carries out a broad range of functions, from translating genetic information into the molecular machines and structures of the cell to regulating the activity of genes during development, cellular differentiation, and changing environments. RNA is a unique polymer." - *UMass Chan Medical School, RNA Therapeutics Institute (RTI) *(https://www.umassmed.edu/rti/biology/what-is-rna/role-of-rna-in-biology/)
The eyes use RNA in fixed situations. It is made in regular maintenance of the cells. It also responds to light brightness and wavelengths. If you go from a light to a dark environment or vice verse it'll spring into action. RNA is made in great quantities to signal that the change has occurred. The RNA arrives in other cells, goes to the DNA, is 'translated' and evokes a reaction. Increasing or decreasing sensitivity to light overall. It also responds to different lightwaves, though not as much.
Here is where we get our magic plausibility. The RNA can be programmed by the creature emitting certain peaks in different light waves in rapid succession. This confuses the RNA process, allowing it to 'hack' the RNA into something else entirely. I would have it produce a cocktail of different RNA that have the following result. First it'll nudge cells into mitosis, or multiplication. During this process they are vulnerable to change. Here is another magic step. It'll reprogram the cell from top to bottom, making it part of the reproduction of the alien. This can be anything from the embryo to a growth sack. Your job is done.
There are a few ways to make it slightly more plausible. The amount of RNA produced in a light interaction is too small and specific to change so much of the body. Instead, the RNA targets either a memory cell of the immune system, or a stem cell. These are changed to produce the hormones and DNA changing material (like viruses). As they can stay and multiply in the body for a longer period of time they can more plausibly work on such large changes.
TL:DR
RNA can have far reaching consequences in the body, which your eyes produce with varying light intensity and colour. With magic the organism steps in and highjacks this system. The RNA then reprograms the body to reproduce the alien.

Thank you! So by your comment it would be best to describe what the "red flash" sends RNA data throught the light waves to alter both the memory cells and immune system of the host to highjack the body´s biology to create and embryo out of it own cells? Would then that mean the mean for the process to be effective it needs the room/place at a certain level of darkness? Given the eyes would react more strongly to a sudden and intense change of the light

@user110409 I wouldn't worry too much about the exact conditions. The suspension of disbelief should cover that part too. Maybe the creature has an innate understanding of the light intensity, changing the pattern to change the DNA. I would also leave most of it unexplained. At a certain moment the more detail you give, the harder it is to accept as plausible. A 'gravity beam' on an alien space ship is ok. If you start describing in detail what it dies, people will focus on the 'bullshit' and start questioning it.

@user110409 as your other question: more or less. The light evokes certain RNA. This changes a memory cell (part of the immune system) or stem cell (a 'can change into any type of cell'). Like a virus infecting a normal cell, these can start producing the required hormones, DNA and RNA to make the body create the alien. From specialised wombs, to specific nutrient production, to the embryo itself.

We already know that electromagnetic waves can transmit information, we do it every day with the internet, and light is a form of electromagnetic wave, so in theory, this should also be able to transmit information. But can it transmit genetic information? Well, we know that our bodies can react to light, a natural evolution due to the importance of the sun. This is highly theoretical (MatPat would be proud of me), but I could imagine a highly advanced organism that emits a special light which gets absorbed through the eyes and triggers the body of said organism to make their body construct and feed an embryo of the alien to gestate a creature akin to the chestbursters from the Alien franchise.

If you want to hand wave it, it's a good explanation. In reality, you need something to interpret that information in the light correctly, otherwise it will be treated by everything as noise, and noise usually can't transmit anything.

I said it's all really theoretical, what more do you want from me?

The alien always was in us already
That means, there is a backdoor in our DNA that either can enable the alien transformation by a specific trigger, or it specifically allows for receiving arbitrary information, encode it in DNA and then activate it.
The red flash of the creature just activates this backdoor. It won't do anything on life forms that don't have it.
How can this be? Well there are options..
Maybe we (or rather our distant ancestors, doesn't need to be homo sapiens, maybe even the other great apes are affected also? That would make the DNA difference less obvious) actually were a slave race to these aliens who left the earth or died out millions of years ago for some reason.
Or they go around the stars in waves, transforming some live forms, infecting some others with their backdoor virus and then leave to come back some later time. In this case they will need to have an additional infection vector for creatures that don't already carry their back door.
But maybe they have gone around the galaxy for so long that they lost that second vector because it wasn't really necessary anymore.

You have answered your own question

I would be using James Kakalio’s rule of Miracle Exception: Every story is allowed one miracle exception to the laws of physics for the story to be still considered ¨realistic¨.


Supposing my story will apply the rule of Miracle Exception. What would be a plausible way to explain how a parasitoid extraterrestrial predator reproduces by passing DNA information through light-waves?

Why, it’s a physical miracle that it is able to do so, but nonetheless it can. You actually already have a semi-decent sci-fi explanation already:

Able to send DNA information through the red light to the host/victim through their visual system, and through it into the host’s nervous system.

If you want it to be slightly-more fleshed out, you can instead write/say

The red light uses amplitude/frequency modulation that, on specific prey, can transmit a large amount of genetic information to anyone who sees it, subconsciously going from the visual system (occipital lobe and related) into the nervous system, through which the “hacked” nervous system can subsequently reach reproducing cells and cause them, like a virus, to use the creature’s genetic information instead of their own.

If I were reading/playing/watching something set in your world, I would 100% buy that. In fact, I’d buy it if you just said

The red light curses anyone who sees it to internally assemble an embryo which subsequently produces the creature’s offspring.

There is a very common misconception that everything in your story has to be “realistic”. If you make absolutely everything in a sci-fi story realistic, you will inevitably end up exactly where we are today, which is not sci-fi anymore. If you want your creature to be able to do this, just say it can and that’s explanation enough! If a more-thorough explanation is required for the plot/gameplay/etc., then make up some stuff that sounds realistic enough and your readers/players/viewers will go with it.
What your readers/players/viewers do not want to do is sit through a half-page/5-minute explanation of biology they likely do not understand (and, if they do understand, will likely find to be flawed). Either they’re bored that they have to sit through it or they’re annoyed that you got it wrong. So just wave a hand if you need it to work, and that will likely be good enough.

I agree with @ControlGroup. You can't say you're using the Miracle Exception and then ask for a realistic explanation anyway. And to be very honest, sending some form of sequential light to human eyes that reprogram the established DNA actions to do something completely contrary to human evolution really is a miracle exception. I further agree with ControlGroup in that the vast majority of readers don't want to sit through pages of textbook while you explain why your miracle isn't a miracle after all.

As I've thought about this, I'd like to introduce to those who haven't seen it, the best Miracle Exception explanation in human history. And it's a fabulous lesson reminding us that it isn't necessary - or desirable - to explain everything.

I feel a plausible reason is missing. The OP is not of the opinion that it is plausible, or wouldn't have said the question. Giving their words back with a minimum of extra fluff then doesn't solve the question for me.

I was never a Babylon 5 fan.  I think the purpose of "sci-fi" is not just to frame a contrived dramatic situation, but to unearth little-known facts about the real world and show how, in various combinations, they might lead to unexpected and interesting outcomes.  It is hypothesis writ large, sometimes vindicated by admiring essays about what the author was able to predict, but still a joy to read even when we know in hindsight the truth was entirely different, due to its combination of patient deduction and outrageous creativity.

@Trioxidane If they’re willing to invoke a miracle, though, then that’s all the explanation they need. The whole point of the miracle is that it can’t be explained, and now they’re asking for an explanation. No expert biologist could come up with a single “plausible” way this could actually work, because it can’t.

A plausible miracle is requested, which can lead to very different answers than 'a miracle'. For me it feels a request to have as little magic as possible. Otherwise the answer 'because they do' is acceptable. As the user is asking the question it clearly is not what they expect. That doesn't make this a wrong answer if it has proper support. In this case I feel that support is not good enough.

“Plausible miracle” seems like an oxymoron to me. If it’s plausible, it’s not a miracle except in the colloquial sense (as in “miraculously, the toaster popped immediately after I was done cleaning up the broken plate”), and if it’s a miracle, it’s not plausible.

@controlgroup This "miracle" terminology seems completely overblown.  It does not have to be a literal miracle to make sense in context of that quote by whoever it was.  For example, a volcano could open up in an East Coast city, or there could be long-term power outage across the east half of the country, but people won't as easily believe both, unless you say "New Madrid all over again" and handwave in how the earthquake caused 'a fissure' and 'liquefaction under the power lines'.  But the better you understand the technical details to support that the better the story.

That’s not a miracle, then, that’s just an improbable event. In that case, either I would have been fine with just accepting “the crust did a silly thing” instead of any explanation at all, or if I do care about the explanation, I’m more annoyed at the author for letting something so crazy happening.

@controlgroup well, the quote doesn't make sense for total violation of the laws of physics.  I mean, you can't write a "realistic" story where the force of gravity suddenly stops affecting anyone with Italian heritage.  You'd at least need some physics fig leaf that the Betelgeusians had received their leader's request for asylum and were helping them with transit or something with a handy force beam... even then it would be a mite far-fetched. :)

If I’m writing a realistic story, I’d have a hard time not also explaining all the Betelgeusian technology, which I would quickly find to be unrealistic in that particular circumstance. I would be perfectly fine reading such a story, but I wouldn’t call it realistic.

A counterexample I'd cite would be Roger Rabbit's infamous "Dip".  It's a substance that can flatten the tires on a bouncy cartoon car.  There's absolutely no plot reason why it would need to be described as a mixture of turpentine, acetone, and benzene rather than fictional 'toon' chemicals.  Nonetheless, the audience should potentially recognize it as a plausible, if carcinogenic, way of destroying old-time celluloid film.  That research matters.  For a great movie, the more you the viewer put into it, the more you get out of it.
